# Output not showing all echo commands

Tags: bash, echo

I'm using a bash script which is run on serverA and connects to serverB to run a file.
The results are saved in a variable and then echo'd. However it doesn't echo all of the data.

The script on serverA is running:

```
count=$(sshpass -p password ssh -t -q user@serverB cd /home/tom && ./count.sh) 
echo "Count: $count"
```

This echos: `341` not `Count: 341`

The count.sh script on serverB is looping through some folders and doing a count of files.

E.g.

```
total=0

count=$(ls -l | wc -l | xargs)
if [ "$count" > 0 ]; then 
    total=$(( total + count ))
fi
echo "$total"
```

How do I display the full echo on serverA?

Comment: `./count.sh` is not executing on serverB. The only thing executing on serverB is the cd command. If you execute `'cd /home/tom && ./count.sh'`, then it will probably be closer to correct. I believe you're not showing the actual MCV example.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to run `./count.sh` on the *local* machine, not the remote host. The `&&` is a command separator that terminates the `sshpass` command. Use quotes to ensure your desired shell command is passed to the remote host.

```
count=$(sshpass -p password ssh -t -q user@serverB 'cd /home/tom && ./count.sh')
```

I don't see anyway of producing the reported output, unless `count.sh` *can* run locally but something (are you using `set -e`?) prevents the following `echo` from executing at all.

Comment: I'm not running `set -e` or more specifically I've not added anything to the script to run that.  I think count.sh was running locally, as I am running to / from the same server for testing, so I think that is messing my results.  Is there anyway to run a command on a remote server and get the result back to the local server ?

Comment: Yes, what I show in the answer. The quotes prevent the `&&` from being parsed as a local operator, so the entire command `cd /home/tom && ./count.sh` is sent to serverB to be executed.